# Why does something work in one editor but not the other?

Tags: errors, editors

I have a Windows desktop at home, running TeXniccenter, and a Linux netbook running Texstudio. I would compile the PDF in Texniccenter without any error, but on Texstudio, I'd get errors. It works the other way as well, i.e. no error on Texstudio but rife with errors on TeXnicCenter.

I often get errors concerning overfull or underfull hbox.
Here's the code in question:
     All that remains to be seeing is whether the partial derivatives of these         functions satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \cdot \frac{1}        
{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \cdot 2x = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \cdot \frac{1
{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \cdot 2y = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &=& \frac{1}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}} \cdot \frac{-y}
{x^2} = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &=& \frac{1}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}} \cdot \frac{1}     
{x} = \frac{1}{x+\frac{y^2}{x}} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

And the error happens right  where the endarray line is.
Why do I get different errors on different editors?

Thank you

Comment: Overfull and underfull hboxes aren't errors; they're warnings. Some editors will show warnings as errors, others will show them differently. If those are the only errors you're getting, there's nothing wrong with your document, it just means that LaTeX can't fit everything onto the lines in a satisfactory way.

Comment: You didn't specify the error, so as @ChrisS mentioned, it might just be a warning. However, are you sure you run exactly the same TeX distribution on both machines each having the same packages? If one machine has newer updates, it might cause these differences. It has nothing to do with the editor.

Comment: Every TeX/LaTeX editor incorporates a TeX/LaTeX error log parser based on various logics for eg: [logParser script](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/source/detail?r=978) and Incase interested refer TeXmaker logparser in [sources](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmaker-4.0.2.tar.bz2) Hence follows "Some editors will show warnings as errors, others will show them differently." as @ChrisS stated.

Comment: Not directly related to the question but you will get better spacing if you us `amsmath` package `align` rather than `eqnarray`.

Comment: With no more detail, we can't hope to answer here: 'unclear', I'm afraid.